# Remove string from a char array

Tags: c#, string, char

I am making a hangman in C# by my own and so far i am doing good. The game works but the letters organize depending on the users input and i want to erase the " _ " from the character everytime the word is found and is on the text.

This is how it looks on the game :

[image]

As you can see , the "_" only disapears for the first letter but not for the others and if the users put the correct answer correctly but radomly some words stick together in many cases and do not stay on their places. This my code for the game:

```
        string word;
        char letter_inserted;
        int correctanswer, incorrectanswer;
        int counter = 0;
        correctanswer = 5;

        Console.WriteLine("welcome to the game of hangman");
        Console.Write("First player please introduce the secret word: ");
        word = Console.ReadLine();

        Char[] sentenceChar = word.ToCharArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Second player you can already play.");
        foreach( char letter in senteceChar)
        {
            Console.Write(" _ "); 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("{0} correcct answers are allowed. \n",correctanswers); //lives
        Char[] correctletter = new Char[5];
        for (int i = 1; i > 0; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n\nWhat letter you want to play : ");
            letter_inserted = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int j = 0; j < sentenceChar.Length; j++)
            {
                if (sentenceChar[j] != letter_inserted)
                {
                    incorrectanswer = correctanswer - 1; //lives
                    Console.Write(correctletter[j] + " _ ");                      
                }

                if (sentenceChar[j] == letter_inserted)
                {
                    correctletter[j] += sentnceChar[j]; //inserting the correct word
                    Console.Write(correctletter[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You should REALLY try to use English in code. Especially when asking questions here.

Comment: It would be so much easier if you were using english in your code. However, let's start from the beginning. Why do you use `for (int i = 1; i > 0; i++)`. I'm not sure about the exact rules of hangman but didn't you have exact numbers of guess to find out the word after which you are supposed to lose the game?

Comment: It also looks like you're subtracting a life for each time a letter is *not* the entered input.  For example, if you had a 5 letter word and entered 'S', and there were no S's, you'd lose 5 lives.  You probably just want to subtract a life if the input does not appear *anywhere* in the array.

Comment: @LukaHorvat yes sorry for that , next time i will do it.

Comment: @Leron that loop is to take user inputs how many times is necesary depending on the lives

Comment: @MikeChristensen you are rigth dude , thats one of the 3 problems i have i thinks that its better make a list and compare the values.

Comment: @JuanCarlosCruz you are just making an infinite loop, I guess in order to see how the other parts of the program are doing. It would be much better to have a `while` loop instead like - `while (desasiertos > 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start with your first sentence - `I am making a hangman in C# by my own and so far i am doing good.` In fact as you can see in the comments there are a lot of things that you would want to consider before going to this exact problem but since you ask how to deal with the extra `_` I'll jump to that.

And a  method :

```
public static void printWord(char[] correctletters)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < correctletters.Length; j++)
   {
    Console.Write(correctletters[j]);
   }
}
```

And then rewrite your code like this:

```
namespace Hangman
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string word;
        char letter_inserterd;
        int correctanswer = 5;
        int counter = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("welcome to the game of hangman");
        Console.Write("First player enter the secret word: ");
        word = Console.ReadLine();

        Char[] sentenceChar = word.ToCharArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Second player you can already play.");
        foreach( char letter in sentenceChar)
        {
            Console.Write(" _ "); 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("{0} correct answers are allowed. \n",correctanswer); //lives
        Char[] correctletter = new Char[sentenceChar.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i <sentenceChar.Length; i++)
        {
            correctletter[i] = '_'; 
        }

        while (correctanswer > 0)
        {
            Console.Write("\n\nWhat letter you want to play : ");
            letter_inserted = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            bool ContainsWord = false;

            for (int j = 0; j < sentenceChar.Length; j++)
            {
                if (sentnceChar[j] == letter_inserted)
                {
                    correctletter[j] = letter_inserted; //inserting the correct word
                    ContainsWord = true;
                }

            }       
            if (!ContainsWord)
            {
              correctanswer -= 1;
            }
            printWord(correctletter);

        }

    Console.ReadKey();
    }


    public static void printWord(char[] correctletter)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < correctletter.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(correctletter[j]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

P.S if you want to make it a little more clear in `printWord` method change the `Console.Write` line like this: `Console.Write(letracorrecta[j] + " ");`

Comment: I cant make the first method work , and the second one i already had it but not as a method but the thing is should i make a char of ' _ ' and for each letter assing it the char?

Comment: The important thing in my idea is to make your code more generic. And this current method is, one to help you overcome the problem with the extra `_` and second - to not have to use hard coded value for the word length as it is 5 chars. See the update code, it should compile and work if everything else is fine.

Comment: OMG it works . thanks alot man . I never was thiking doing like that thanks !! . You are the man . I lke programming and some times it takes me alot to overcome a problem , im pretty sure this was so easy for you hahahaha

Comment: you say the messages of the code translate them all to engish?

Comment: First, to be honest I'm not very happy that I gave you a working code, because that's not the best way to find out how and why something is working, but I got confused myself several times so I ended up writing this but I really hope that you'll examine the code and look through the things that you couldn't figure out by yourself.

Comment: As for the messages - I just didn't understood them and I thought that maybe with my code you'll need to change the meaning, not the language. But You can still add some additional messages like how many lives left you have, or "Congratulations" if you win the game but in general, the reason to tell you to change the messages was because I misunderstood some of them and thought they need to be changed in order to make sense.

Comment: hahah no man , dont say that you gave me the working code , you cleared out the problem that i have (the ' _ ' problem). you gave me the methods and then i tried them but couldnt make the work because i wasnt undertanding something you wrote. But sorry for that. you were rigth about the methods with that idea i could have done it but wanst paying attetion to this part: letracorrecta[i] = '_'; and this  letracorrecta[j] = letra_insertada;

Comment: No problem :) Wish you happy programming. Hope I helped.

Comment: Since someone has kindly provided a translation of the code in the original question it looks like you're now obliged to translate the code in the answer too. ;-)

Comment: @LeonBambrick hahah yeah dude . i took the responsabilitity to do that . I translated all the code that were in spanish . Didnt change the image because the important is the code not the image.But if you want i can change the image.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a different approach for this.  Create two arrays, one for the solution:

```
var solution = new char[] {'H', 'A', 'N', 'G', 'M', 'A', 'N'};
```

And one for the current hint.  At the beginning, you'd initialize this to:

```
var hint = new char[] {'_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'};
```

When a letter is guessed, you can loop through `solution` and each time `solution[i]` is equal to the guessed letter, *replace* the corrosponding index in `hint`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < solution.Length; i++)
{
   if(solution[i] == guess)
      hint[i] = guess;
}
```

At the end of this loop, just re-write `hint` onto the screen, which will always contain the current hint.

A few things you'll want to do:

1. Have a Boolean within your loop to track if `solution` contained any instances of the letter.  If not, at the end of the loop you'd subtract a life.  You can also do this *very* easily using `solution.Contains(guess)` as well.
2. Perhaps create a `List<char>` to track already attempted guesses.  If this list already contains the entered letter, you can display "You already guessed that!", otherwise add the guess to the list.

This answer is meant as a hint to get you going in the right direction, rather than a complete solution.  However, feel free to ask if any part of it is unclear.

Comment: ok the contains(guess) , I undertand that but im using the array letracorrecta to catch the letters whats the difference in using a list?. Can you explain me that

Comment: No real difference.  A `List<>` is implemented as a hash table, so you can very quickly see if it already contains a certain key without having to loop through each item.  It's a bit faster (not noticeable in this case) and keeps the code a bit cleaner.